# Taking backup of mysql database using mysqldump through PHP script

Tags: php, backup, mysql

I am running the following PHP script to take backup of my database but the code is not running as expected and the attend.sql file is not generated

```
<?php
exec('mysqldump -uroot -prahu attendance > attend.sql', $result);
foreach ($result as $ line)
    echo "$line\n";
echo "DONE";
?>
```

Comment: What did you expect and what does it do differently? And what kind of output does your script produce? Do you see `DONE` or some of the lines that you would expect as output from the commandline?

Comment: I expect attend.sql file as a backup file of attendance database, there is also no output of line (echo "$line\n";) but DONE is being displayed on browser window